# Eclipse cant run properly

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, hibernate, spring-mvc

Hi everyone here i having some problems with my Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers.
I´m using Ubuntu 17.10
Today i was learning how to create a web application with java everything was going nice still i tried to open a jsp class that couldn´t be displayed so i decided to restart my IDE but now it allways say me this:

[image]

And this is the .log

```
    !ENTRY org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core 4 0 2018-01-19 18:32:46.730
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.BeansCorePlugin.stop() of bundle org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.stop(BundleContextImpl.java:855)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.stopWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:947)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.stopWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:314)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStop(Module.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.stop(Module.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.decStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1675)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1594)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.SystemModule.stopWorker(SystemModule.java:270)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$SystemBundle$EquinoxSystemModule.stopWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:147)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStop(Module.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.stop(Module.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.SystemModule.stop(SystemModule.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$SystemBundle$EquinoxSystemModule$1.run(EquinoxBundle.java:165)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.eclipse.core.runtime.AssertionFailedException: null argument:
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Assert.isNotNull(Assert.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Assert.isNotNull(Assert.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.ResourceChangeListenerList.remove(ResourceChangeListenerList.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.NotificationManager.removeListener(NotificationManager.java:313)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.removeResourceChangeListener(Workspace.java:2206)
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.internal.model.BeansModel.stop(BeansModel.java:189)
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.BeansCorePlugin.stop(BeansCorePlugin.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$4.run(BundleContextImpl.java:835)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$4.run(BundleContextImpl.java:1)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.stop(BundleContextImpl.java:828)
    ... 13 more
Root exception:
org.eclipse.core.runtime.AssertionFailedException: null argument:
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Assert.isNotNull(Assert.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Assert.isNotNull(Assert.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.ResourceChangeListenerList.remove(ResourceChangeListenerList.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.NotificationManager.removeListener(NotificationManager.java:313)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.removeResourceChangeListener(Workspace.java:2206)
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.internal.model.BeansModel.stop(BeansModel.java:189)
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.BeansCorePlugin.stop(BeansCorePlugin.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$4.run(BundleContextImpl.java:835)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$4.run(BundleContextImpl.java:1)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.stop(BundleContextImpl.java:828)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.stopWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:947)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.stopWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:314)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStop(Module.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.stop(Module.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.decStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1675)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1594)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.SystemModule.stopWorker(SystemModule.java:270)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$SystemBundle$EquinoxSystemModule.stopWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:147)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStop(Module.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.stop(Module.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.SystemModule.stop(SystemModule.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$SystemBundle$EquinoxSystemModule$1.run(EquinoxBundle.java:165)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

1.I really dont know what is happening,i read in the .log something
   about Spring framework but i didn´t used it already and i have
   installed the framework last year.

2.And if you can help me with some tips to learn spring and hibernate you are      welcome.

Comment: You should write that error message into your post as text, rather than providing a link.

Comment: The link provide a screenshot of the issue of my screen but anyway it say An error has occurred please read .log

Comment: Log reads similiar to this post [Eclispe Wont Run](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1088896/), maybe try the suggested fix that reported worked: `"Perhaps deleting <workspace>/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.e4.workbench/workbench.xmi, i.e., resetting the workbench's UI state back to the default, will work around the problem."`

Comment: It works thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this same issue.

1. Delete everything to do with Eclipse, then
2. install it again and make sure it is the 32bit launcher. 64bit processors can run 32 bit programs so this will cover that.
3. Make sure you have the latest JDK downloaded BEFORE installing Eclipse.

I know it shouldn't matter, but this cleared it up for me.

All of these errors seem to be coming from Eclipse itself.